# Automatically import necessary classes in Android Activities without Eclipse or Android Studio

Tags: netbeans

I have a question. If there's any possibility to automatically import necessary classes when I work with Activities in text editor (gedit) or Netbeans? Because Android Studio is incredibly slow on my PC.

I mean `import android.app.Activity` `import android.os.Bundle` etc.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM:
according to [Netbeans doc](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/editor-codereference.html#imports):

> There are several ways of how you can work with import statements. The IDE's Java Editor constantly checks your code for the correct use of import statements and immediately warns you when non-imported classes or unused import statements are detected.
>
> When a non-imported class is found, the Bulb error icon error mark appears in the IDE's lefthand margin (this margin is also called the glyph margin). **Click the error mark and choose whether to add the missing import or create this class in the current package**.
>
> While you are typing, press **Ctrl-Shift-I (or choose Source > Fix Imports from the menu)** to add all missing import statements at once.
>   Press **Alt-Shift-I to add an import only for the type at which the cursor is located**.
>
> When you **select a class from the code completion window, the Editor automatically adds an import statement for it**, so you do not need to worry about this.